# Dragon Ball Volume 1 colored and uncensored?

Tags: dragon-ball, merchandise

I would like to buy  for my collection a copy of Dragon Ball Volume 1 colored and uncensored or the closest thing.

Browsing I have found so far:

1. Regular Volume 1 is uncensored but no color pages.
2. Collectors edition has some colored pages but is censored.
3. Viz Big has some colored pages but is censored and is really big.

I am wrong?  Any other choice?

Comment: Do you also want it in English? If so, as far as I know what you're looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: I prefer English but I am open to Japanese if is the only option.